# How to dynamically create FieldLists using Fask forms

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-wtforms

My use case is as follows:

In the home/index page the user is asked to enter the number of companies that he has worked so far. Based on the number that he has supplied he will be redirected to another form in which he would have to supply the names and the location of all those companies.

Below is my code base for the same:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,redirect,url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField,PasswordField,IntegerField,BooleanField,Form,FormField,FieldList,ValidationError
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'MySecret!'

class CompanyDetailsForm(Form):
    company_name = StringField('Company name')
    location = StringField('Location')

class CompanyForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self,entries):
        self.first_name = StringField('First name')
        self.companies = FieldList(FormField(CompanyDetailsForm),min_entries=entries)

class IndexForm(FlaskForm):
    no_of_companies = IntegerField('No of companies worked so far')

    def validate_no_of_companies(form,field):
        if field.data > 5:
            raise ValidationError("No of companies cannot be more than 5")

@app.route('/CompanyDetails/<number>',methods=["GET","POST"])
def company_details(number):
    form = CompanyForm(number)
    return render_template('Companies.html',form=form)

@app.route('/home',methods=["GET","POST"])
def home():
    form = IndexForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('company_details',number=form.no_of_companies.data))
    return render_template('home.html',form=form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Below is my home.html page :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
    Please enter below details 
    </h1>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.no_of_companies.label }}
    {{ form.no_of_companies }}
    {% for error in form.no_of_companies.errors %}
    <ul>
        <li style="color:red">{{ error }}</li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And below is my code base for Companies.html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Companies Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
    Please enter below details 
    </h1>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.first_name.label }}
    {{ form.first_name }}
    {% for l in form.companies() %}
    {{ l.form.company_name }}
    {{ l.form.location }}
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But i am getting an impossible to understand error like :  'UnboundField' object has no attribute '**call**'.

Please guide me in this.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is not to really worry about it!

When you create your form, you're setting your business and validation logic, I'm going to cheat a little and say:

```
min_entries=5
```

Never can someone fill in six entries, but there's a chance they've worked less then five.  We can deal with the empty ones.

With that logic taken care of-- now you just need to worry about the user-interface size, so lets adjust our route slightly to get better data straight away:

```
@app.route('/CompanyDetails/<int(min:1, max:5):number>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def company_details(number):
    form = CompanyForm(number)
    return render_template('Companies.html', form=form, companies=number)
```

Then in our template we could just do:

```
{% for x in range(companies) %}
    <li>
    {{ form.companies[x].company_name.label }} {{ form.companies[x].company_name }}
    {{ form.companies[x].location.label }} {{ form.companies[x].location }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

If we change the URL, the template renders the correct amount-- for example if we go too high (`/CompanyDetails/6`) we'll get a 404 error.

If I were less lazy, I could set `min_entries=1, max_entries=5` and build the form more manually:

```
{% for x in range(companies) %}
    <li>
        <label for="companies-{{x}}-company_name">
            Company name
        </label>
        <input 
            id="companies-{{x}}-company_name" 
            name="companies-{{x}}-company_name" 
        type="text" value="">
    </li>
    {# ETC #}
{% endfor %}
```

Which could be considered more explicit, but even best would be to get JQuery to add the form elements as required-- saving the user going through the first 'How many companies?' form, and instead just having a '+' button which would add another company element dynamically as needed, up to the maximum allowed.